# Mounting NFS share over VPN at system start

Tags: openvpn, nfs

I try to mount a nfs share on a server that is connected via OpenVPN.
Both systems are Ubuntu 18.04 server. and are vpn clients of a third system with client to client config.
Manually mounting the NFS works as expected.

Only at system start the share is not mounted. I suspect that the "client" tries to mount the share before the VPN is established.

What is the recommended way to solve this problem?

My configuration:
/etc/exports on the server:

```
/documentArchiv         10.11.0.61(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/documentArchiv         10.11.0.60(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

/etc/fstab on the client

```
10.11.0.6:/documentArchiv/ /documentArchiv nfs user,soft,intr,exec,nosuid,noatime,nodiratime,_netdev 0 0
```

Comment: I'd configure the mount as `noauto` and use a netplan (or VPN-client) script to mount the share. Which OVPN client is used?

Comment: The openvpn packed with Ubuntu 18.04 is used for the clients and for the server.
Do you have a link how to do the mount with netplan?